# Build React JS docker image npm install error Could not resolve dependency and Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, dockerfile

can someone tell me the problem with my Dockerfile , i tried build image react js with docker and somehow it always show error when step run npm install

dockerfile

```
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .
#COPY . .

#RUN npm install -g npm@8.19.3
#RUN npm install react-scripts
#RUN npm ci
RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "app-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^4.5.8",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.9",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.8",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "blueimp-md5": "^2.19.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-excel-export": "^1.0.6",
    "react-excel-renderer": "^1.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.55.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "homepage": ".",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

and i have very very long package-lock.json

i tried to change npm install to npm install -g npm@8.19.3 from npm suggestion, and  after i change dockerfile, it success build image, but when i tried to run container, it says

```
> app-test@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

sh: react-scripts: not found
```

can anyone tell me where am i wrong ?

Comment: Your `package.json` file has React 18.2.0 listed as the current version. Likely one of your other packages depends on React 17.0.2 or your package-lock file has a different version. Run `npm audit` outside of your Docker container and it should tell where the conflict is.

Comment: can i add run job in dockerfile to do npm audit? cus i dont want to install npm on host server @Tim

Comment: Can you run npm audit on your dev computer where you wrote the app? You don't need "run" in your command list. Also, react-scripts are for the development environment and `start` only runs a development server.